# Using a component from a local component library in my main project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, rollupjs

I am creating a component library using React, TypeScript, Rollup, and Styled Components. Now I have come quite far but I'm stuck at what I think is the last part.

I have my button component in my library being exported from it. Now I am able to import this button component to my main project after I've installed it, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I'm doing nothing much more than editing the standard React beginning page like this:

```
import "./App.css";

import { ButtonBase } from "aab-react-emerald";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ButtonBase>Button</ButtonBase>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have compared both the package.json files, and I think they're fine:

Library (removed some stuff that was unnecessary):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.76.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  }
```

Project (removed some stuff that was unnecessary):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.43",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "aab-react-emerald": "file:../../aab-react-emerald",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Does anyone know where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my component library. The issue was caused by multiple versions of React. Solution found in [this comment](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe#comment-269bb). By running `npm ls react` you can list the different React versions.

To solved this I added `external: ['react', 'react-dom']` to my `rollup.config.mjs` file:

```
// Imports ...

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist/cjs/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: 'dist/esm/index.js',
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [...],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];
```

Hope this helps!